# Reading specified byte from NSData - output to label

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I have a file which is loaded into a buffer. The file comes from an URL, and contains 31 bytes. So far so good.

How do I read a specific byte, let's say byte number 20, and then output a normal decimal ("converted" from binary) to a label?

For reference I've loaded the file into a NSData variable called 'data', an my label is called 'currentBattery'. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[data bytes]` and treat it like a character array and read 20. Or `[data getBytes: &byte range: ...]`

```
((char*)[data bytes])[20]
```

Would be the simplest.  I would check the length of the data to be sure first.

Comment: I know that byte 20 is only one byte long, where should i state that?

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", (char)c] or even @"%c".  If you want to be sure then mask it 0xFF & (char)c

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get the byte out I wanted, but now I cannot get it to display a normal number on the label. It spits it out in the console as a hex (2e), and when I connect it to a label, it says: "2013520544". How do I connect my byte variable (d1) to a label, and display it in normal numbers?

Comment: Mask the value off like I said.  It would be the same as doing char x = ...; [NSString stringWithFormat: ..., x];  It is likely displaying the large number because it is reading other values in the data when you do %d

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 0xFF & ((char*)[data bytes])[20]];  That says I only want to display the first byte worth of whatever is there